# Facebook messenger bot - receives single and very first message

Tags: facebook, bots, webhooks, messenger

Facebook messenger bot - receives single and very first message continuously at every 2 minutes.

I have created bot in PHP and set webhook. But I am receiving webhook trigger at every two minutes  no matter I have added/received new message or not.

One more thing is that we are receiving only very first messages. There are so many new messages after that message but we are receiving single message only.

Where am I incorrect? I have followed this article :
http://blog.adnansiddiqi.me/develop-your-first-facebook-messenger-bot-in-php/

Comment: Make sure your webhook endpoint answers with 200 OK quickly enough (I think the maximum allowed is six seconds) - otherwise Facebook will consider this an error, and try and send the same update again.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got the solution:

```
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$sender = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
$message = isset($input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text']) ? $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'] : '';
if (!empty($input['entry'][0]['messaging'])) {

    foreach ($input['entry'][0]['messaging'] as $message) {

        $command = "";

        // When bot receive message from user
        if (!empty($message['message'])) {
            $command = $message['message']['text'];
        }
        // When bot receive button click from user
        else if (!empty($message['postback'])) {
            $command = $message['postback']['payload'];
        }
    }
}



$pagetoken = "PAGE TOKEN"; // Facebook TOKEN
if ($command) {

    if ($command == "hii") {
        $message_to_reply = "test_response";
    } else if ($command == "need more info") {
        $message_to_reply = "Please fill form at link ";
    } else if ($command == "\ud83d\ude00") {
        $message_to_reply = "smiley";
    }

    if ($message_to_reply != "") {
        $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=$pagetoken";
//Initiate cURL.
        $ch = curl_init($url);
//The JSON data.
        $jsonData = '{
        "recipient":{
        "id":"' . $sender . '"
        }, 
         "message":{
            "text":"' . $message_to_reply . '"
         }
       }';
        $jsonDataEncoded = $jsonData;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        if (!empty($input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message'])) {
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}

header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');  //  This line needs to be added

die;
```